# adding and removing the selected class to a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK so now I have my sliding open ul revealing all the list elements, and now I want the title bar that is clicked on to have a state of selected added to it, and then remove that state when it's closed...

the div above the UL has a class of .regionHeader

here's an example of the mark up

```
<div class="regionHeader">title of the region</div>
<ul class="region"><li>the region i'm hiding/showing</li></ul>
```

here's the javascript

```
var stockists = {

start: function() {
        $('.region').hide();

            $('.regionTitle').each(function(){

                $(this).click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $(this).parent().next('.region').slideToggle(300);
                });                     
            });
        }            
};

$(stockists.start);
```

I've been trying addClass but it seems to just add the class and not remove it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().toggleClass('activeTitle'); // toggling the class on the parent
$(this).parent().next('.region').slideToggle(300);
```

Answer (score 5):

Can you not use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

This way the class will be added/removed when you need it to be.

```
$(this).parent().toggleClass("className");
$(this).parent().next('.region').slideToggle(300);
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove a class from an element you have to use [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

```
 $(element).removeClass("classname");
```